# Firestore Security Rule limit field entry

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my Firestore document, I am trying to limit the fields that the users could update to only the ones I allow. I thought about a function that could check if `request.resource.keys()` contains any keys that are not the ones I allow, if it does, I block `update`, if not, I allow `update`. so far, my function looks like this:

```
function field_limit() {
      let allow_keys = ["field1", "field2", "field3"];
      return request.resource.keys() in allow_keys;
    }
```

inside the path match:

```
allow update: if field_limit();
```

When I run a unit test in Emulator that modifies "field1", it does not pass. I think I am doing something wrong here because I am comparing the whole `keys` list against the `allow_keys` list.
What should I do in order to achieve the desired functionality then?

I thought about a solution to iterate through `request.resource.keys()`, and see if each key is `in allow_keys`. If one isn't, block `update`. But how to traverse through each value of a list?

***edit***. Should be `request.resource.data.keys()` instead of `request.resource.keys()`. Otherwise, it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `in` operator doesn't work the way you're expecting.  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) for that - it only checks if a **single** value is in a list.

If you want to check if a list of values contains only a subset of values in another list, you should use [hasOnly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasOnly) instead.

```
request.resource.keys().hasOnly(allow_keys)
```

This will evaluate true if the list `request.resource.keys()` contains only values from the `allow_keys` list.

Comment: Modified the function to `return request.resource.keys().hasOnly(allow_keys);` from `return request.resource.keys() in allow_keys;` But still fails at the same test that modifies "field1"

Comment: I found what was my problem, it should be "request.resource.data.keys()"